# How can i check to see if somethings already written to a txt and give an error if so python

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a school project and I have to make a voting system that uses a voting code. I need help with the code that opens up the 2 files, checks to see if the code is there and gives a value error if it is.

```
while True:
        Code = input("Enter your 6 digit code: ")    
        try:
            Code = int(Code)
            if "0" in str(Code):    break
            if len(str(Code)) != 6 :   raise ValueError
            else:   break
            readt = open("Trump.txt" , "r")
            readh = open("Clinton.txt" , "r")
            readhh = readh.read()
            readtt = readt.read()
            if Code in str(readtt) or Code in str(readhh):  raise ValueError
            else:   break
            readt.close()
            readh.close()
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid")
```

Comment: 'while True:
        Code = input("Enter your 6 digit code: ")    
        try:
            Code = int(Code)
            if "0" in str(Code):    break
            if len(str(Code)) != 6 :   raise ValueError
            else:   break
            readt = open("Trump.txt" , "r")
            readh = open("Clinton.txt" , "r")
            readhh = readh.read()
            readtt = readt.read()
            if Code in str(readtt) or Code in str(readhh):  raise ValueError
            else:   break
            except ValueError:
            print("Invalid")'

Comment: Can you please put your code in the [code] tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple pointers to fix your program:

The `if len ... else` part seems to leave the `while` loop either through `raise` or `break`. The code that does `open` is never executed.

Also you call `open` a lot of times. This will become problematic because [leaking file descriptors is a problem](http://www.martin-ueding.de/en/articles/c-file-descriptors/). Use the `with open(...)` statement for this. This way, you cannot leave the file open by accident. Your `close` statements are behind another `if ... else` construction that will leave the loop in every case.

Your variable names are a bit opaque, perhaps you want to invent some more telling ones.

Why are there two files? Shouldn't there be only one file that contains all the used codes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you presented all the information in your question this is the solution for your problem:

```
def code_checker():
    codes = []
    with open('Trump.txt', 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            codes.append(line.rstrip())
    with open('Clinton.txt', 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            codes.append(line.rstrip())
    code = input('Enter your 6 digit code:\n')
    while True:
        if '0' in code or len(code) != 6:
            print('Invalid code\n')
            code = input()
            continue
        elif code in codes:
            raise ValueError

code_checker()
```